# expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality - Throws this error when the response has the ternary condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am learning unit testing with Jest,
This is the function I trying to test.

```
import axios from "axios";

export const call = async () => {

 return axios.get("https://www.example.com").then((resp) =>{
     const response = resp.data
     let userData = {
         title : response.title ? response.title : "",
         url : response.url ? response.url : "",
         date : response.date ? response.date : " ",
         id : response.id ? response.id : "",
         email: response.email ? response.email : ""
     }
     return Promise.resolve(userData)
 })
}
```

here is the test.js file ---

```
import axios from "axios"
import {call} from './components/call'

jest.mock('axios')

const expectedResult = {
    title:"hello"
}

const resp ={
    data : expectedResult
}

describe("test", ()=>{
    test("demo-test", async ()=>{
        axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(resp)
        const response = await call()
        expect(response).toEqual(expectedResult)
        
        console.log("axios.get() returns >>>", axios.get.mock.results[0]);
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://www.example.com")
    })

})
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 0
    + Received  + 4

      Object {
    +   "date": " ",
    +   "email": "",
    +   "id": "",
        "title": "hello",
    +   "url": "",
      }

      16 |         axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(resp)
      17 |         const response = await call()
    > 18 |         expect(response).toEqual(expectedResult)
         |                          ^
      19 |
      20 |         console.log("axios.get() returns >>>", axios.get.mock.results[0]);
      21 |         expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://google.com")
 FAIL  src/call.test.js (7.597 s)
```

In the call.js, when userData dosen't have ternary conditions then the test passes. But when I put ternary condition the test gets failed with the above error. Please help me. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can we assume "when userData dosen't have ternary conditions" means each property looks something like `title : response.title`?

Comment: In your `expectedResult` the properties `date`, `email`, `id`, `url` are `undefined` while in `call()` they have a empty string as default value. So why do you expect the test to pass?

Comment: @Cat yes it will be `title : response.title`

Comment: so, if there are default values, then in the `expectedResult` I have to define all the properties? @lbsn

Comment: Which one is correctly implemented, your test or your function? If you expect the properties to be initialized as `undefined` than your test implementation is correct and you need to change your `call()` implementation to let the test pass. If you expect them to be initialized as empty strings then your test implementation is wrong and you need to change the `expectedResult` object. By the way, it looks from your code like the `date` property actually contains a space.

Comment: Another option might be that in your test you actually don't care about properties other than `title` (I don't know what you're actually trying to test here). If that's the case just change the check: `expect(response.title).toEqual(expectedResult.title)`